# how to secure an HTTPs trigger function that increment user's balances from hackers

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple game on android that calls an HTTPS firebase cloud function to increases the player's balance after finishing game round, the problem I have some hackers who are calling this function frequently in order to increase their rewards, how I could protect this function from being abused ? any logic I can implement on the client side ?

```
// this is a simple function that increases the player's balance after the game.

const MAX_REWARD = 1000;            

  exports.GameFinish = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

        if (!req.headers.authorization) {
         console.error('No Firebase ID token was passed');
         res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
         return;
         }


        res.contentType("application/json");


        if (req.query.userID) {
            userid = req.query.userID;
        }
        else {
            return res.status(404).json({'msg': 'Error', balance: 0, errors: 'no user ID was supplied'});    
        }


        if (!req.query.award) {
            return res.status(404).json({'msg': 'Error', balance: 0, errors: 'no award was supplied'});  
        }



        var award_amount = parseInt(req.query.award);

        if( award_amount > MAX_REWARD)
        {
            console.log('rewards exceeding the max limit!', result);
            award_amount = MAX_REWARD;          
        }



        admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.headers.authorization).then(decodedIdToken => {
            return checkUserExists(userid).then((userinfo) => {
                if(userinfo != null)
                {


                var ref_prize = admin.database().ref("/game/${userid}/total_prize");
                        ref_prize.transaction(function(totalPrize) {
                        return totalPrize + award_amount;
                        });
                }
                else 
                    // error user is not in the record
                    res.status(200).json({'msg': 'Error', balance: 0, errors:  'no such a user exists'}); 

                });

        }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error while verifying Firebase ID token:', error);
        res.status(403).send('Unauthorized'); });   

    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't the balance be updated internally as a part of the finishing the game round in the same transaction? I mean why to expose the balance update API to the external world. And if it must be exposed, should there be some synchronous or asynchronous mechanism to validate if the user's action deserves a balance update. For e.g. maybe the balance update API needs a game instance id to be provided and if the api logic finds that there has already been an update for the game instance id, or if the game instance id does not even played, of the game inst id expire there wouldn't be any update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of abuse is fairly common in games. You'll want to protect against it by implementing any or all of these:

1. Pass in the ID of the game that was finished, and verify that each finished game can only count once for each player. This is by far the most effective improvement, since it makes it impossible to increase the score without playing a game.
2. Only return a basic error message in the response, and rely on logging for the actual problem. This means the attackers will have a harder time determining how your code works by inspecting the errors.
3. Pass information about the gameplay of the game that was finished, verify that this was a valid set of moves, and determine the reward on the server. So instead the player saying "I won with this many points", have them say "I made these moves". Your function then determines what the game state is after these moves, and determine winner and reward. Note that you might already be recording the moves in the database during gameplay, in which case you only need the player to pass in the game ID.
4. In general keeping a record of the moves is a good way to be able to analyze them to detect false play. Even if you don't do this analysis today, having the moves makes it possible to do this later (if needed).

All of these will have to be implemented in the server, e.g either in Cloud Functions or in Firebase's server-side security rules. By definition the clients can not be trusted to be running your code.

There are probably a lot more of these practices, but these were the first that jumped to mind here.

Btw: congrats on having a game successful enough that players are trying to hack it! :-)